# How do the JVM and Java implement reading from and writing to files?

Tags: java, file, jvm

In Java, you can read from and write to files. But the JVM can run on many systems that may have different ways of storing files and related data. How does one write JVM code that works on every system?

At what level are native methods used? Does the JVM have a certain set of file functions that must be implemented for each system, and which are then can be called by any language? Or does each language that runs on the JVM (like Java, or Scala) have to do it itself?

Comment: The JVM wraps OS native file functions for most OS's. Languages written for the JVM don't have to worry about it.

Comment: http://www.grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/io/FileSystem.java#FileSystem

Comment: @Slaks - that's just the Java code.   A lot more happens on the native code side.  Certainly the stuff to do with reading and writing files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Typically, you would write the JVM in a high-level language like C++ and then use that language's provided libraries for interfacing with the file system.  You can then compile the JVM on different platforms, OSes, and architectures and leave the responsibility of determining how to do file I/O to the high-level language compiler.

Alternatively, for certain operations, the JVM might have different implementations of file I/O or windowing based on the operating system it runs on.  There would then be multiple different implementations, and when building the JVM on a system the compiler can determine which one to use based on a `config` script, or `#ifdef`s, etc.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Okay, so if the JVM wraps all the OS-specific stuff for you, how do you call/use that stuff in JVM code (like if you were writing a compiler that would generate JVM code for a new language)? Also, is this how reading from and writing to the console works too?

Answer (score 1):

Most IO functions are pretty standard and there are POSIX calls which work across multiple operating systems.  Where there is a differences, the relevant code can be included or not using the C pre-processor with `#ifndef` and `#ifndef`

Comment: From my previous brief visits to the OpenJDK JVM codebase I got the impression that there were separate implementations of the native code APIs for different operating systems.  It is (to a significant degree) not just done with conditional compilation.

Comment: @StephenC Even in Java there are implementation classes like WindowsFileSystem and UnixFileSystem which are only available on those systems.

Answer (score 1):

Reading from and writing to file is done in java.io.FileInputStream / FileOutputStream classes by calling native methods eg

```
private native int readBytes(byte b[], int off, int len) throws IOException;

private native void writeBytes(byte b[], int off, int len, boolean append)
        throws IOException;
```

These classes are the same for all platforms only the native methods implementation differes, in my Oracle HotSpot it's `jre/bin/java.dll` library